# How can I detect g++ and MinGW in C++ preprocessor?

Tags: c++, g++, mingw, c-preprocessor, gnu

I want to do something like:

```
#ifdef GCC
#define GetFunctionName() string("My function name is ") + __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
#endif
```

Since I want to use `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, this is only supported by GNU as far as I know so I need to detect if I am compiling for g++ and MinGW, how can I do that?  I'm guessing all I need to know are the compiler's preprocessor definitions, like I did for Microsoft below:

```
#ifdef WIN32
#define LogFuncBegin() gLogger.FuncBegin( __FUNCTION__ );
#define LogFuncEndSuccess() gLogger.FuncEndSuccess( __FUNCTION__ );
#endif
```

How can I detect g++ and MinGW in the C++ preprocessor?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can make use of:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#ifdef __MINGW32__
```

For additional macros you might be interested in [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20160308010351/https://beefchunk.com/documentation/lang/c/pre-defined-c/precomp.html) which shows other compiler macros.

Comment: Did your test cases include MinGW-64?

Comment: @jww No but MinGW-64 will also define the 32 macro, so this would work for that as well.

Comment: A more up-to-date version of that compiler macros list is in the [Pre-defined Compiler Macros project at sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Home/)

Comment: The link to "this page" is dead.

Comment: Or `__GNUG__` which is equivalent to `(__GNUC__ && __cplusplus)` if you want to distinguish C++ from C.

Comment: Wayback Machine archived version of the linked page: https://web.archive.org/web/20160308010351/https://beefchunk.com/documentation/lang/c/pre-defined-c/precomp.html - though I concur with @rakslice that a more up-to-date list like https://github.com/cpredef/predef is preferable.

Answer (score 50):

For GCC:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
```

For MinGW:

```
#ifdef __MINGW32__
```

x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc defines both `__MINGW32__` and `__MINGW64__`.

Comment: Did your test cases include MinGW-64?

Comment: This answer was written pre-MinGW-64.  But I think that defines the `__MINGW32__` macro as well.  So should still work

Comment: This is kind of a moot point. I can't find a [MinGW-64 offered by the project](http://www.mingw.org/).... There's no sense in solving a problem that does not exist....

Comment: @jww MinGW-w64 is a hard fork of MinGW, because MinGW didn't do a great job. Pretty much everyone uses MinGW-w64 these days, not the original MinGW. Same with MSYS2 and MSYS.