# Determine GCC Compiler with Macro

Tags: c++, gcc, macros, nasm

> **EDIT:** Ha ha, search terms are a weird thing. I actually had to use the answer I got as a term for the search to *finally* find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493759/how-can-i-detect-g-and-mingw-in-c-preprocessor). In the spirit of StackOverflow, I'll vote to close my
>   own question as duplicate instead of deleting it, in case it'll serve as a landing point for
>   someone else.

I am writing several functions that are using `asm`, but I only want them to function when they're compiled with a compiler that can work with NASM. (I'm on C++11, by the way.)

I'm a little bit new to the whole concept of `asm`, but this is what I **think** I know:

- GCC and its "relatives" (MinGW, TDM-GCC) use NASM, which is what I'm writing my functions for.
- All Intel and AMD processors can theoretically understand NASM, regardless of operating system, because...
- The X86/X64 assembler is determined by what the compiler implements.

Assuming the above is correct, **what macro can I use to ensure that the functions I'm writing are defined if and only if I'm using a GCC (or similar) compiler, or a compiler that uses NASM?** (The `#ELSE` would be a usable dummy version of the function to ensure general compatibility with other compilers.)

The only macros I know about of this sort relate to determining operating system (such as `#IFDEF _WIN32`), but that macro would incorrectly get used in the situations where I'm compiling with TDM-GCC or MinGW on Windows.

> NOTE: In case anyone wonders, the functions in question are basically
>   "helpful, but not vital" utility functions. We don't have any plans to
>   compile with a non-GCC compiler, but it's open source code, so we want
>   to be considerate of others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`__GNUC__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) macro to identify GCC (and some mostly compatible compilers like Clang and Intel's C++ compiler).

MinGW (any version) can be checking for `__MINGW32__` and/or `__MINGW64__`.

Comment: Awesome. So, that will also recognize `TDM-GCC` and `MinGW`, I assume?

Comment: Ha ha, silly me, I finally found the duplicate of my own question. All the same, I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me. Thank you!